# Decorators for Zend_Dojo_Form

Tags: dojo, zend-form, zend-framework

I have a Zend_Dojo_Form and like to change the decorator for it:

```
//inside my Zend_Dojo_Form
$this->setDecorators(array(
        'FormElements',
        'DijitForm',
        array(array('tr' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'tr')),
        array(array('table' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'table')),
    ));
```

The rendered form looks fine but if I submit only Zend_Form_Elements, but no Zend_Dojo_Form_Elements are POSTed. If I do not change the decorators, all values are submitted, but the layout is (of course) broken. Do I miss some essential decorator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be more html than zend related

```
    $this->setDecorators(array(
        'FormElements',            
        array(array('tr' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'tr')),
        array(array('table' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'table')),
        'DijitForm',
    ));
```

works, because now the form elements spans the whole table.